# Передать клик на чекбокс

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, checkbox

Вот макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
                               <div class="table_row">
                                    <div class="table_cell">
                                        <div class="checkbox checkbox_2">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="ch_1" />
                                            <label for="ch_1">09/05/2019</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table_cell">
                                        <p>5</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table_cell">
                                        <p>200</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table_cell">
                                        <p>10 %</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table_cell">
                                        <p>20 +</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table_cell">
                                        <p>5 +</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table_cell">
                                        <p>56657</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Нужно чтобы при клике на родитель .table_row передался клик на checkbox_2 input.
То есть нужно что бы при клике на строку таблицы был выбран или отменен чекбокс в первой ячейке. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без скрипта, через общий label вместо div - тоже работает, но я не уверен, что это законно)

```css
.table_cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #b89868;
}
```

```html
<label class="table_row">
  <div class="table_cell">
    <div class="checkbox checkbox_2">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes"> 09/05/2019
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table_cell">
    <p>5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_cell">
    <p>200</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_cell">
    <p>10 %</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_cell">
    <p>20 +</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_cell">
    <p>5 +</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_cell">
    <p>56657</p>
  </div>
</label>
```

Без jQuery:

```js
let row = document.querySelectorAll('.table_row');

for (let i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
  row[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    let check = this.querySelector('.checkbox input');
    check.checked = !check.checked;
  });
}
```

```css
.table_cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #b89868;
}
```

```html
<div class="table_row">
  <div class="table_cell">
    <div class="checkbox checkbox_2">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes"> 09/05/2019</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table_cell">
    <p>5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_cell">
    <p>200</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_cell">
    <p>10 %</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_cell">
    <p>20 +</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_cell">
    <p>5 +</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_cell">
    <p>56657</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function{
    $('.table_cell').click(function{
        if($('#ch-1').is(':checked')){
            $('#ch-1').attr('checked',false);
        }else{
            $('#ch-1').attr('checked',true);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

можно как вариант попробовать следующее:
(только не уверен , что  именно нужно, .table_cell или .table_row )

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
  $('.table_row').click(function(ev){
   if(!$(ev.target).is('label,input')){
      $(this).find('input').trigger('click')
   }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table_row">
                                    <div class="table_cell">
                                        <div class="checkbox checkbox_2">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="ch_1" />
                                            <label for="ch_1">09/05/2019</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table_cell">
                                        <p>5</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table_cell">
                                        <p>200</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table_cell">
                                        <p>10 %</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table_cell">
                                        <p>20 +</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table_cell">
                                        <p>5 +</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table_cell">
                                        <p>56657</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```